# Is there a way to show only one country using leaflet and fit to the screen of my laptop?

Tags: laravel, leaflet

I want to show only one country (in my case Tanzania) using leaflet and that country should fit to the screen of my laptop...

[image: Leaflet Map]

I try loading the coordinate of country using the code below

```
$.getJSON('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/johan/world.geo.json@34c96bba/countries/TZA.geo.json').then(function (geoJSON) {
    var osm = L.tileLayer("https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png");
    map.addLayer(osm);
    var tzLayer = L.geoJSON(geoJSON);
    map.fitBounds(tzLayer.getBounds());
});
```

but I want it to fit to the screen of my laptop.

Comment: See https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-zoomsnap

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I use zoomsnap option and atleast works perfect.